# knockout + partials + mvc + correct way to bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, partials

Dear fellow programmers

I got myself into a pickle. Ive been in to knockout for like 2 weeks now and im afraid i dont understand the basic idea of it. So be gentle with me.

Situation:

I got a master view layout page /Master to make it simple. Here i got 2 column layout.
On the left a listbox with patients, after clicking one, you will see prescriptions added to the listbox below it. pretty simple...

[image]

Dont mind the renderbody here, this is faulty. Just use this image to see 2 big parts. The red en and the yellow.

Now i got the Master working pretty well, when i click on a patient i want to load a specific partial view on the yellow part of the screen. The same with clicking a prescription , then i want to load the prescription partial on the yellow part.

I got these 2 editscreens working but without the master included. these pages look like this:

```
@model  FysioNotes.WebMVC.Models.ViewModels.EditPatientViewModel
```

form + bindings here

@section scripts {

```
<script src="~/MyScripts/patientVm.js" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new editPatientVm(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))));
    });

</script>
```

}

You see that i use razor here to fill in the data in the editPatientVm. the js file looks like this :

```
var patientVm = function (data) ...
var editPatientVm = function (data) ...
var createPatientVm = function (data) ...
```

This is the same with the prescriptions .
Now when i try to load the prescription partial into the yellow part of the screen, i try to do it like this. And this is probably very faulty....

```
-- this is at the bottom of the master view --
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('#tablePrescriptions').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
               var selectedId = $(this).data("prescriptionid"); 
    // this data gets filled without troubles
               $(this).addClass('selectedrow').siblings().removeClass('selectedrow');
               openDetail("prescription", selectedId);
            });
```

and then this function

```
    function openDetail(type, selectedId) {
        if (debug)
            alert(type + " : " + selectedId);

        var url = baseurl + "/Prescription/Edit?prescriptionId=" + selectedId;

        $("#mainContent").load(url);

        //CHECK THIS
        ko.cleanNode($("#mainContent")[0]);
        $("#mainContent").load(url, function () {
            //ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), $("#mainContent")[0]);

            ko.applyBindings(new editPrescriptionVm(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new FysioNotes.WebMVC.Models.ViewModels.EditPrescriptionViewModel(12836)))), document.getElementById("mainContent"));
        });

    }
```

like you see , the fixed number 12836 is totally wrong to do it like this. But i wanted to just try if this would work and it did. But apparantly i cant send a js var to razor , because this is impossible.... so this let me to the idea that im doing something completely wrong

the master view has this at the bottom:

```
<script src="~/MyScripts/patientVm.js"></script>
<script src="~/MyScripts/prescriptionVm.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new masterVm(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))));
    })

</script>
```

I think i need to put the viewmodels that i need in the partial into my viewmodel of the master maybe ? and then send it trough but this will mean that EVERY viewmodel needs to be on the master. This cant be good for initial loading !  And this seems wrong to me to do it like this , but ive been wrong before....

please help :(

Answer (score 1):

@section scripts cannot work in partials views that are retrieved through ajax... you'll have to execute your code between those tags after the code that retrieves the view in the first place. @section scripts is kept into the request items and rendered when the page is rendered. But since this is ajax, the server has long passed the point where it would keep into account scripts defined between this section